Would a question about how to transport aviation equipment as checked baggage be appropriate here?
I created a question on travel.stackexchange.com that asks about how to confidently get a paramotor onto a commercial airline flight as checked baggage. Although the question has been read and commented upon, there's no definitive answer, and I wondered if the aviation community here would be a better source of information. But I was concerned the question might not be aligned with policy. Please advise.

Welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. I am in two minds about this. On one hand: putting an aircraft in an aircraft is very much an aviation thing, on the other hand: airline policies on checked bags are typically considered as the domain of travel.stack, not of aviation. Since paramotoring is a form of aviation, my gut feeling says that we should be open to this question as it is about a problem that other aviators may have as well. Let me post both views as possible answer and then the community can vote.

Thanks.  As a pilot, it's a problem I'm facing.  I understand not wanting to talk about "airline policy". What if the problem was in shipping an aircraft via ground transportation?  An analogous situation might be if I were a pilot asking a question about shipping an ultralight via truck?  Both are problems that a pilot is having when undertaking activities relating to managing aviation equipment.

Yes, we should allow such questions.
Although in general this site does not discuss airline policies on checked luggage (travel.stack is good for those questions), in this case the question deals about an actual problem an aviator is facing when practicing his sport (how do I transport my aircrafton an aircraft). Since we welcome the paramotor community as part of aviation.stack,
the question should be allowed.

No, questions about checked luggage and airline policies are off topic here.
Although the question is about putting a paramotor (aviation) on a commercial aircraft (also aviation), the actual question is about airline policies and how to transport combustion engines. That is not the domain of aviation.stack and may be better at travel.stack.

"Just because stackexchange A is better for a question than stackexchange B, doesn't make it off-topic on B" and vice versa have long been SE policies. Many questions are on-topic in multiple places. A question about transporting sports equipment would normally be on-topic on that sport's forums.
Case-by-case basis is definitely the right approach here. Is the question about how to carry generally heavy luggage (airline domain), or about how to disassemble and prepare sensitive, oversize, and/or dangerous equipment, specific to that SE, for transportation?

Yes, the question is how a pilot would need to prepare specific aviation-related equipment for transportation.

The question of whether questions about checked luggage in general should be on-topic here at Aviation.SE has been answered here before in the negative.
However, I think this particular question should likely be on-topic, not because it has anything to do with airline checked luggage, but rather because the question is specifically about how to transport a particular type of aviation-related gear that involves special considerations that pilots would be more likely to have experience with. It would also be on-topic if asking about how to transport that gear as air freight or by some non-air source of transportation in my opinion.
(With that being said, I don't think we should give advice about how to circumvent airline policies and the quotes in the question from AA, DL, and UA's websites seem to suggest that this is not supposed to be allowed on those airlines.)
